# JSF visibility on ICEFaces Push update - strange behavior

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, xhtml, icefaces

I have a problem with conditional rendering of JSF components updated with ICEFaces Push.

The use case is I'm looping through images in directory, and on new image I'm calling ICEFaces Push Renderer, so that xhtml page will get an updated image and its info. Image is shown in one panel, while its info - in another. The info is not always accessible, and when it's not - I want to show a team logo instead of info panel. This is the xhtml code:

```
<ice:graphicImage height="1024" width="768" value="#{viewBean.image}"></ice:graphicImage>
    <h:panelGrid border="0" columns="1">
        <c:choose>
            <c:when test="${viewBean.infoAccessible}">
                <h:panelGrid border="0" columns="2">


                    <h:outputText value="Data:"></h:outputText>
                    <h:outputText value="#{viewBean.info.time}"></h:outputText>

                </h:panelGrid>
            </c:when>
```

The code above, together with server-side codes work as intended, but there's a strange side effect I do not understand. There should be 1 call of viewBean.image, but it increments... so as the app runs - I get up to 70+ calls to this method, which is not the case, when I remove the viewBean.infoAccessible condition check.

... I can provide also a server-side sources, but there's no direct interconnection between viewBean.image and vievBean.infoAccessible (also some other ppl had a look at my codes).
So - what's the problem here? What am I missing?

Is there any other way to hide/show JSF components on ICEFaces Push update?

Answer (score 0):

I use the `visible="#{mybean.visible}"` attribute to control the
visibility of my ICEfaces components from my Java managed beans.

I am not surprised that you get some strange results
mixing `<c:choose>` and ICEpush because that makes it
difficult for ICEfaces/ICEpush to determine what has changed on
the page and needs to be pushed to the client.

Can you use the `visible` attribute and managed beans
to turn components on/off without `<c:choose>`?
Then all the logic for page display is in managed beans
and not in JSF pages.